# Same VBA code in the same worksheet for 2 different sets of table the first works, the second doesnt

Tags: excel, vba

I found the below code to input a timestamp automatically when one specific range has anything written and I wanted to do this in 2 specific places within the same worksheet, hence I wrote the same sequence, however the 1st works and the second doesnt, below my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'==============logdate timestamp completed============
Dim myTableRange As Range
Dim myDayTimeRange As Range


'my Data Table Range
Set myTableRange = Range("E:E")

If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then

'Column for the date
Set myDateTimeRange = Range("A" & Target.Row)

If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then

    myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
End If

End If


'==============logdate timestamp inflight============
Dim myTableRangeif As Range
Dim myDayTimeRangeif As Range

'my Data Table Range
Set myTableRangeif = Range("N19:R19")

If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRangeif) Is Nothing Then

'Column for the date
Set myDateTimeRangeif = Range("J" & Target.Row)

If myDateTimeRangeif.Value = "" Then

    myDateTimeRangeif.Value = Now
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Just changed the code as suggested however the timestamp appears on the "A" column but not on the "J" one

Comment: `If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` - because when you change something in `Range("N19:R19)` the `Exit Sub` gets executed.

Comment: @BigBen i completely spaced on that being a change event... was thinking "loop over two sheets" and saw `range()`.  comment removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change something in `Range("N19:R19")`, the `Exit Sub` is executed because it is true that `Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing`.

You need to change the logic of `Exit`ing the `Sub` if the `Intersect`ion is nothing.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then
    'Column for the date
    Set myDateTimeRange = Range("A" & Target.Row)

    If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then
        myDateTimeRange.Value = Now
    End If

End If

...

If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRangeif) Is Nothing Then
    'Column for the date
    Set myDateTimeRangeif = Range("J" & Target.Row)

    If myDateTimeRangeif.Value = "" Then
        myDateTimeRangeif.Value = Now
    End If

End If
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? More explanation please. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58861922/edit) your question with the revised code you're using.

Comment: @SergioFlorez don't edit my answer, but edit your original question.

Comment: @SergioFlorez, I added that code to my sheet and made a change to `N19`, and I got the timestamp in `J19`. Is that not what you're doing?

Comment: Yes that is what I pretend but I dont get the timestamp in J19

Comment: I can't replicate that.

Comment: Sorry BigBen it worked like a charm I have corrected range to N:N instead of N19 andstarted to input the time stamp, as well my data was not including zeroes on blank spaces now its all doing what I wanted to do thanks